# load UIWebView when clicking a button

Tags: ios

```
-(IBAction)loadWebView
{
  NSString * url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [_urlArray objectAtIndex:_urlInt] ];
  NSLog(@"_urlInt: %d",_urlInt);
  NSLog(@"get url: %@",url);
  //[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[ NSURL URLWithString: url ] ] ];
  [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[ NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]]];
}
```

The above is my code in an iPad project.
 
It triggers this method when clicking a button on the same View Controller or click a row of a table on different View Controller.
Values of _urlArray and _urlInt are from the table when I click a row of the table. I can get the url in this method but I cannot relaod the UIWebView. However, when I modify the url to the home page of google and I click the button, the page can be reload to google.com.

I cannot get the reason. Could someone teach me that? 
Thanks...

Comment: Its really weird. Can u just share what the logs u get. There must be some problem with URL format

Comment: Please share the logged value of url.

Comment: I am also having the same issue, when I open my app the UIWebView is not loading, after refreshing only the webview is loaded. Also when I click on the logout button the webview is not loading.So can anyone help me with this issue.